# Motion tracking. Long shot

Tags: tracking

I’ve got a footage 1 minute long filmed from a car. The scenery changes a lot in the side window. So there’s no way I could set common markers. They would go off the screen 5-10 times.

**What’s the best practices in this case?** All I found is to remap “old” markers to the new area by setting offset. But it seems I’m missing smth and there should be a simple solution for such a common scenario.